# Closing my LG Quick Cover disables alarm clock

Tags: nexus-5, alarm

I've recently bought a Nexus5 and a LG quick cover, and I discovered something very bothering : 
When I set an alarm clock and close the cover, the alarm doesn't vibrate as I'd expect. I need to keep the cover opened to hear the vibrations.

Does anyone know a solution for this?